# How to copy in the folder, knowing only part of its path?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Source dir:
`C:\srcDir`
Target dir:
`C:\Users\'unknown'\targetDir`, 'unknown' = any name (not subpath).
What will be a script for copying source dir to target?

Comment: Based on what should unknown be resolved? Do you want to copy to all directories under `Users` or the first or what?

Comment: Problem is that i know exactly only two parts of target path:
'C:\Users' and 'targetDir'.

Comment: +Known parts of path are concrete names.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It's like you are asked to put a ball in one of ten boxes. You are not told which box, but you have to put it inside the correct box anyway. How do you know which box to put it in if, as you're saying, you don't know which box?

Comment: @slider: you may want to edit this question to reflect what you were really trying to figure out: how to get the current user's home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%userprofile%` is a environmental variable that you can use.

i.e.
Target dir:

```
%userprofile%\targetDir
```

You can type set and press enter at a prompt to see what environmental variables exist for your use.

If you just want the part, then look at `%username%` which is what that part is.

for dir copy, you can use xcopy, i.e.

```
xcopy "C:\srcDir" "%userprofile%\targetDir"
```

Type `xcopy /?` in a prompt for available arguments to use.

Comment: Thanks. What I looked for!